# Repeater in ASP.NET - Trying to connect it with a datasource that calls a SP on SelectCommand, getting multiple errors

Tags: asp.net, datasource, repeater

I have a stored procedure to list items on my database that receives the 'user_mail' parameter. I want to display the results on a repeater but the combination of declaring a parameter and the loop nature of the repeater is causing me problems.

See I have the following code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlLogList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer %>" 
            SelectCommand="ws_log_list"> 

        <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="user_mail" DefaultValue="ALL" />
        </SelectParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

On code behind if I use the following code, clearing the parameters,I get an error saying there's a parameter that needs to be declared. If I remove the .Clear() I get an error saying the parameter user_mail is being declared multiple times!

```
SqlLogList.SelectParameters.Clear();
        SqlLogList.SelectParameters.Add("user_mail", "bomb@cryo.com.br");   


        repeater.DataSource = SqlLogList;
        repeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Then don't add it again... just set it:

```
SqlLogList.SelectParameters.Clear();
SqlLogList.SelectParameters["user_mail"].Value = "bomb@cryo.com.br");   


repeater.DataSource = SqlLogList;
repeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! But it's saying 'System.web... does not contain a definition for 'Value'. Edit: Doesn't work with 'DefaultValue' either. OBS I'm using .net 4.0

Comment: Been a while since I used one of these, not 100% on the syntax any more.  Have a hack around, this should lead you to the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntex is wrong, missing `@` for parameter name. It should be:

```
SqlLogList.SelectParameters.Add("@user_mail", "bomb@cryo.com.br");
```